# Can't start MongoDB, mongod is always stop/waiting

Tags: mongodb, putty

I was editing my `mongod.conf` on puTTY and to apply the changes I had to restart the service

but after doing so and checking the status it says

```
mongod stop/waiting
```

and when i run the command `mongod`

I get this error

```
exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, any help is appreciated

Comment: Well, the error message says that "/data/db", where it expects to find its data, doesn't exist. The first thing is to follow that up - have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yeah i created the file using "sudo mkdir -p /data/db" and the db is running now but my website is not picking it up for some reason, any clues?

Comment: The error is a **red herring** *"...  was editing my mongod.conf on puTTY"* - So the configuration file contents are now **invalid** from whatever change you actually made, and such pre-existing settings like those for `dbPath` are being ignored. YAML has strict indenting guidelines, and it's likely you managed to press the tab key or something similar which is not allowed. Make sure all indenting is "spaces" and check the configuration keys [against the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/). Once the config is valid, the options will be used at start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's having a similar issue, this is what fixed my issue.

after running this `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` to create the directory

make sure to rerun the app/api for the the website to communicate with the db again

That fixed my issue. Hope this helps